# How to check weather speaker is in use or not in android?

Tags: android, audio, android-service, android-audiomanager, speaker

I am using audio manger but how to check if speaker is in use or not?

**audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);**

Comment: You want to check that android device has an internal speaker or not?

Comment: No, i want to check if speaker is playing or not. It may be music , ringtone or any other notification sound etc. I want to check weather speaker is playing or not..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean activeFlag = audioManager.isMusicActive();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the method [isMusicActive](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#isMusicActive())() of the audio manager it returns true if any of the music is playing